# "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter" with same parameters

Tags: c#

Ok, I know this questions has already been asked and solved, and I solved my problem too.
But mine was a bit different, and mostly : I want to understand what's happening !

I used to see this error because of missing parameters in a constructor.
But in my case, both constructors have the same amount of parameters (and obviously the same type).

Here's an exemple. Here's the beginning of a Weapon class, that inherits from a Mover class :

```
abstract class Weapon : Mover
{
    protected Game game;
    private bool pickedUp;
    public bool PickedUp { get { return pickedUp; } }
    private Point location;
    public Point Location { get { return location; } }

    public Weapon(Game game, Point location)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.location = location;
        pickedUp = false;
    }
}
```

And here's the Mover class :

```
abstract class Mover
{
    private const int MoveInterval = 10;
    protected Point location;
    public Point Location { get { return location; } }
    protected Game game;

    public Mover(Game game, Point location)
    {
        this.game = game;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

This way, I get the "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter" error for Weapon's constructor. But paramaters seems to be OK !

If I call constructor like it :

```
public Weapon(Game game, Point location) : base(game, location)
{
    pickedUp = false;
}
```

Then it's ok. Why do I get this error ?

Something with the scope of my variables ? With their namespaces ?

I'm following a book, and the first examples I gave was what they want us to write, and should be OK. Is there new ways of using constructors and/or methods with inheritance ? Am I doing something wrong in the first Weapon's constructor and/or in my second one ?

Comment: Because you need to call a `base(...)` constructor.

Comment: That changed "recently" ? It's mandatory ? It is not said at all in the book I'm reading, and they keep using constructor without using "base".

Comment: Are you sure that in example of your book weapon class inherit mover? It looks like not

Comment: No, it's not newer version. There is wrong using Inheritance at all. Because you don't need rewrite code which you have in parent class (location/game)

Comment: This might be a side note, but an abstract class should not have a public constructor.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182126.aspx

Comment: If you have code to share, please [edit] your question to include it. Comments are not good for that purpose. Although it looks the same as what's already there; if so, no need to put it in twice :).

Comment: Sounds like you got a bad book, frankly. That's just not how inheritance is done in C#.

Comment: Comment deleted Heretic ;)
Thanks for advices, still not used to StackOverflow.

@bhmajler Thanks a lot. Indeed, it make sense.
Never trust blindly a book !
Thanks you all :)

Comment: He's quite good for learning.
But like a lot of books I read, there's some little errors. But yes it can be a pain to understand as you give trust to him. And on the otherside, it make you search the truth and learn \o/